# How do I change Diablo 3's parental controls? 

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't seem to access the Real Money Auction House because it's telling me that I cannot access it due to parental controls or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access parental controls, log into Battle.net.

- Go to 'Account'
- Settings > Parental Controls

Then enter the email used for parental controls. Once that address opens the email, Parental Controls can be set which includes checking a box that lets you use the Real Money Auction House.